# Is it possible to get the content of the to be executed script(its filename, or content) in __name__ == '__main__' block?

Tags: python-3.x

Can we have access to the executing script path or its textual (source code) form when we do

```
[script logic] 
several functions()
etc
main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get the script path, read it and manipulate or get information concerning it 
    #  or if the physical path is unavailable, get the contents
    Do_the_manipulation_or_get_stats()
    # then run the actual functions, etc
    main()
```

To make this more clear, suppose I want to show what the size of the executing script is and prior to running it (executing the main()), show the size along with some other stats on the screen. (possibly send these as arguments to main() to print them as logs etc).
If so, how can I go about this? i.e either getting the physical path or the content?

Comment: maybe this will help `os.path.abspath(__file__)`

Comment: @Preetham, thank you, yeah, I noticed that already and wrote an answer.

Comment: oops!! sorry , page was not refreshed and i just added it...

Comment: no problem, thank you for your kind help. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `__file__` one can get the path of the current executing script.
and with this specified, we can easily achieve what we have in mind, for example for getting the md5 hash of the current script we can simply write :

```
some_functions()
main()
import os
import hashlib
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = os.path.realpath(__file__)
    file_contents = None
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        file_contents = file.read()
    hash_code = hashlib.md5(file_contents.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    main(hash_code)
```